# How can find this pattern in php string?

Tags: php, regex, search

How can find and extract the next pattern in a php string, I only need extract the content between `"sources":[.......]`, the content is variable,

```
"more":[{.....}], 
"sources": [
{"file":"url1","label":"360p","default":"true"},
{"file":"url2","label":"480p"},
{"file":"url3","label":"720p"},
{"file":"url4","label":"1080p HD"}
], 
"morestuff":[{......}]
```

this is a string object as result from scrap tag  from external page using simple_html_dom.php, so when i make var_dump to this data the result is string, this is why i think the regexp with php can help me to find those values

Comment: `json_decode` this is not just a random string

Comment: thanks, i forgot say, this is a string object as result of a scrap tag <script> using simple_html_dom.php so if i make a var_dump to this, i get as result string object